# HTMLUNIT, get Ajax answer while waiting Form answer

Tags: java, ajax, htmlunit

I send a file to the server from a Form

`onSubmit` event launches a `setInterval` which asks the server about the file percentage that is uploaded, and I show it dinamically with JQuery.

When click `submit` button with HtmlUnit ( `submitButton.click()` ), it keeps waiting the answered page. So I can't see what ajax get.

`NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController()` doesn't work.
`waitForBackgroundJavaScript()` doesn't work.
I created a child thread before `click()` to try to check what ajax is receiving, but it looks that is waiting form action too.

How could I get two answer at same time? Any ideas to get it and know how long I would have to wait?

Thank you in advance

Since you ask for it, but real code is very complex, I'm going to write a simple example.

This is main HTML code

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function Upload() {
        setInterval("waitProcess('x')", 2500);
}
function waitProcess(uid) {
    $.get('x2.php?id='+uid, function(data) {
      $("#t").val( $("#t").val() + "\n" + data );
    });
}
</script>
<form action="x3.php" onSubmit="Upload();">
<input type="file" name="file">
<input id="boton" type="submit" value="Transfer it" />
</form>
<textarea id="t"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, file is uploaded by form. I use async AJAX requests to see the percentage of file is already uploaded. I just use a `<textarea>` to show the example answer.

What I want with my HtmlUnit code is keep reading current HTML in `WebClient` to see if `<textarea>` is been updated by Ajax request. But `WebClient` is blocked while form is uploading the file.

Comment: Can you post your full case, with the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I fear you are facing an issue with HtmlUnit. Asnc requests are not really async at the moment.
Please open an issue for this; if possible provide some sample code.

BTW: is the file upload done by a form submit or is this also an async request?

Comment: Both things same time @RBRi. File is been uploaded by `form submit` while async requests are checking how long does it take